# Exporting logo animation from after effects to use as loading

Tags: javascript, css, animation, loading, after-effects

Small animations files to try here : https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/25c485d490e415a430464bb6258958c320170214000506/eda56579b69e291a497414b7fd52024d20170214000506/093842

I'm not developer I'm just an designer so sorry for my lack of knowledge.

How do I export the logo animation from after effects to be used as loading animation on my website?

I tried plugin Bodymovin it does work, but not on all browsers.

And sorry for any typos english is not my native language

Thank you all guys in advance!

Comment: You have to export it as a .gif

Comment: Thank you Mike,but I wanted to have it stay vector svg like,so it doesn't loose sharpness when scaled responsively ,any workaround for that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with AE, does it have an ability to export in .svg format? I mean is your question about .svg compatibility with some browsers or you are asking for an ability to save from AE into .svg? To say why it's not working well in browsers, would be nice if you share the code first, so ppl can see an issue and help you.

Comment: yeah I will try send those files for look,and maybe you guys see whats the issue,it doesnt wrk on every browser.I'm waiting for files will send asap

Comment: @Mike you can donwload small files here :  https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/25c485d490e415a430464bb6258958c320170214000506/eda56579b69e291a497414b7fd52024d20170214000506/093842 ,just drag and drop into your browser and you can see how it works,let me know if any idea how to make it work on more browsers. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look, but you better update your question with this info, so the other guys can find it easily.

Comment: Whats seems to be the problem? I check in IE, Chrome, Edge, Mozilla Firefox, Opera and even Safari 5.1.1 - works smoothly.

Comment: @Mike thats the problem it works on mine too,but doesnt work on couple more pcs I tried on. No clue why

Comment: But how can we suggest how to solve the problem if we don't see the problem? If you have an access to that mysterious PCs, take some screenshots to demonstrate the wrong behavior, gather an information like browsers' versions, console errors and so on.

Comment: @Mike I really not sure why it doesnt work on every pc,and Im not developer so no idea haha,Thank you for help,and I will wait if more guys developrs can try it on their and if thy all say it work,than nothing is issue anymore :)

Comment: I may assume that you are saying about old browsers that doesn't support some language (JS) functions used in the animation code.

Comment: @Mike  they used latest browser version, on windows 10 x64 bit,so might lack some other stuff in their ps  ome update maybe who knows,I just want it work on majority of browsers and such. Thanks again man

Answer (score 0):

@nellement

As far as I know Adobe removed FLV and F4V, which were the codecs used to export a flash movie, which is I think what you are looking for.

You might be able to do it if you still have an older version of either After Effects or Adobe Media Encoder.

If you don't you best bet will be to use H.264, that is what Adobe is recommending, see this post

[removal of FLV and F4V export features from Adobe Media Encoder, After Effects, and Premiere Pro](https://blogs.adobe.com/creativecloud/removal-flv-f4v-swf-export-adobe-media-encoder-after-effects-premiere-pro/)

Things to take into account for your animation, how long is the animation, how big in screen size, 1920X1080, or is it just a banner, if it is full screen, can you go for a smaller size?

You can render an Animation 100 from after effects then run it thru Media Encoder using some of their sample setting until you get something that works for size and quality.

I hope this is of some help

Comment: Thanks for recomendation,but I would like it to stay in format as it is now ,sharp and crips,if use video it will look blurry I think at different sizes and bigger file size I think. can you take a look at wetransfer files i linked above they very tiny